# How to read nested json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created an object like this.

```js
myObj =  {
   "name":"John",
   "age":30,
   "cars": [
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
   ]
   }
```

I can easily read name and age but I want to read the content (key values) under object "cars". I want to put key values in the drop-down so that if select any key from cars then I will get respective values.
Thank you!

Comment: `myObj.cars.car1`, `myObj.cars.car2` ... Also, just FYI that's an object literal, not JSON.

Comment: It would be easier if you made the cars object an array. You'd get "cars": ["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"].

Comment: Do you want to read the values or the keys?  What's your expected list of values?  "car1,car2,car3" ?  What you've described is:  `<select><option value="Ford">car1<option><option value="BMW">car2</option>` - ie "select a key (`car1`) get value (`Ford`)" - this seems the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do it by `myObj.cars.car1` , `myObj.cars.car2` and , `myObj.cars.car3` to get directly or loop as below example

```js
var myObj = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "cars": {
    "car1": "Ford",
    "car2": "BMW",
    "car3": "Fiat"
  }
};

for (let i in myObj) {
  if (typeof myObj[i] == 'object') {
    for (let j in myObj[i]) {
      console.log(j, myObj[i][j]);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(i, myObj[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use dot operator , by which you can access the properties

```js
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": {
        "car1":"Ford",
        "car2":"BMW",
        "car3":"Fiat"
    }
 }
 console.log(myObj.cars.car1);
  console.log(myObj.cars.car2);
   console.log(myObj.cars.car3);
```